# Google tag manager rest api - trigger creation with filter returns an error

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am trying to create a new trigger by using google tag manager rest api and getting this error:

Unable to parse trigger data com.google.analytics.containertag.common.CtApiaryException: trigger.filter[0].parameter[1]: Filter's second argument must be string.

This is my payload:

```
const body = {
                accountId: googleTagManagerAccountId,
                containerId: containerId,
                workspaceId: workspaceId,
                name: `Bla bla PageViews Disabled JS - ${domainUrl}`,
                type: 'pageview',
                tagFiringOption: 'somePageViews',
                filter: [
                    {
                        parameter: [
                            {
                                type: 'template',
                                value: '{{ Cheq Essentials Variable }}',
                                key: 'arg0',
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'boolean',
                                value: 'false',
                                key: 'arg1',
                            },
                        ],
                        type: 'contains',
                    },
                ],
            };
```

can someone explain me please what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you are using boolean and value you are passing is in string 'false' so either you need to update value or the parameter should be 'template'

Option 1 : change type in filter

```
filter: [
                {
                    parameter: [
                        {
                            type: 'template',
                            value: '{{ Cheq Essentials Variable }}',
                            key: 'arg0',
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'template',
                            value: 'false',
                            key: 'arg1',
                        },
                    ],
                    type: 'contains',
                },
            ],
```

Option 2 : change value as boolean

```
  filter: [
                    {
                        parameter: [
                            {
                                type: 'template',
                                value: '{{ Cheq Essentials Variable }}',
                                key: 'arg0',
                            },
                            {
                                type: 'boolean',
                                value: false,
                                key: 'arg1',
                            },
                        ],
                        type: 'contains',
                    },
                ],
```

Comment: Option one worked for me! thanks @hiren207